# Using css only, how to select html elements inside a div/class but exclude some nested div/classes

Tags: html, css

Here is a simplified page struture, where I want to select all images inside the "page"-div and enclosed elements, but not those that are in either "keepoffa" or "keepoffb".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div class="page">
       <img/> <!-- OK -->
       <div class="keepoffa">
          <img/> <!-- never take this-->
       </div>
       <div class="keepoffb">
          <img/> <!-- never take this-->
       </div>
       <img/> <!-- OK -->
       <div class="subpage">
           <img/> <!-- OK -->
           <ul>
               <li>
                   <img/> <!-- OK -->
               </li>
           </ul>
       </div>
       <ul>
           <li>
               <img/> <!-- OK -->
           </li>
       </ul>
    <div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's what I have thought:

```
.page img:not(.keepoffa):not(.keepoffb) {
    max-width: 300px;        
}
```

But the unwanted divs are not excluded.

**How to effectively select the images but exclude the images inside those unwanted divs? CSS-only required.**

Answer (score 1):

Use `>` operator to select the child of `.page` div. And `.subpage img` to the another image

```css
.page > img,
.subpage img{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
  <div class="page">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/> <!-- OK -->
       <div class="keepoffa">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/> <!-- never take this-->
       </div>
       <div class="keepoffb">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/> <!-- never take this-->
       </div>
       <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/> <!-- OK -->
       <div class="subpage">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/> <!-- OK -->
       </div>
<div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a good idea. Unfortunately, the real page is more complicated than my simplified example above. Thus, working with immediate children selectors does not work that easy. I would have to include paths for every possible layout path. This will get too complicated. I will update the example a bit to represent this better.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use two pseudo-selectors simultaneously (and your selectors weren't correct anyway).

EDIT: Probably the easiest way is something like this:

```
    .page img {
        max-width: 300px;
    }

    .keepoffa img, .keepoffb img {
        max-width: initial;
    }
```

Comment: this also needs .page > img added on

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yep :) CSS is often quite funky

Comment: @Mike Yep you're correct - misread his original question. Going to update my answer when I get a chance

Comment: Hm, this seems not to exactly work, since it an image is only inside one of them, it still gets selected with the other one.

Comment: @Marcel Oh yes, I forgot about that. I ran into a similar issue a few months back. Let me re think this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.page>img,
.page div:not(.keepoffa):not(.keepoffb) img {
    max-width: 300px;        
}
```